# Word to describe something that is "great" and "terrible"

Tags: word-choice

Looking for a good word to describe Paradise Lost's Satan. My brain thought "magnanimous" but then I looked that word up. I want something like "magnificent" (which I may use) because it comes from "magnus" but I want there to be the undertones of evil. Malignant doesn't quite get there because I want to get across the sheer Greek heroic stature of Satan. Suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: "Maleficent" sounds amazing, but unfortunately isn't remotely related to "magnificent".

Comment: Is "Maleficent' a real word? I thought it was a pun.

Comment: I thought it was a pun too, but [it's real](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/maleficent).

Comment: The original meaning of 'terrible', i.e. inspiring terror, might well work for you.

Comment: Yes I think I might go with "great and terrible".

Answer (score 1):

awesome:

> inspiring great awe or fear

In this case I'm referring to the older sense of the word that was used exclusively for God. However, because the meaning has so changed, writing "awesome Satan" might arouse some concern.

consummate:

> being of the highest or most extreme degree

Consummate carries a very superlative connotation. It also has the Latin stem *summa*, meaning highest or greatest.

*Lovecraftian* conveys feelings of immense power and evil, but may be too particular.

Hope one of these helps!

Comment: The problem with "awesome" is the more idiomatic modern use that simply means "cool".

Comment: awesome is perfect.  Catija, you just have to ignore people that dumb  :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, *diabolical*, natch.

Or *malovent*, *baleful*, *sinister*, <strike>*heinous*.</strike>

*Terrible* itself would have been a great fit in prior times, like "the great and terrible Oz" in that Oz was terror-inducing.   But now we use *terrifying* which isn't as good an adjective for people.

Answer (score -2):

I'd go with nefarious! Famously wicked.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).